# Query by post title

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I've used a custom post type for one of my website. Custom post type contains scratch card data along with some custom fields.

I've developed an android application to manage those items from android device.

In the android app, I want to keep search feature which will help admin users to search card numbers to manage those.

I can use wordpress query to search by title.

```
Code
$args = array("post_type" => "mytype", "name" => $title);
$query = get_posts( $args );
```

It can only provide result if I provide exact title. But I need to retrieve all items with similar title.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of using `get_posts()` you can use the default search query of `WordPress` which will provide you the results of the searched term. It will also provide all the matching results with all your search terms.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use either [search parameter of wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) :

```
Code
$args = array("post_type" => "mytype", "s" => $title);
$query = get_posts( $args );
```

Or you can get posts based on title throught [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
global $wpdb;
$myposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $title ) .'%') );
```

Than you'll get post object in this form:

```
foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) 
{
    $post = get_post( $mypost );
    //run your output code here
}
```

Comment: Is this working in 2019?

Comment: Note that using `s` in `get_posts` will search more than just the title though... it also searches the content.

Answer (score 11):

Much simpler nowadays:

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'  => 'recipe',
    'title' => 'Chili Sin Carne',
]);
```

`$posts` will contain all recipes with the **exact** title "Chili Sin Carne".

Comment: OP was asking for a fuzzy match

Comment: Oops, you're right. I only read the title :$

Comment: thank you. it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts([
            'post_type'   => 'recipe',
            'post_status' => ['publish', 'draft', 'private'],
            's'           => 'search string',
            'search_columns' => ['post_title']
        ]);
```

This will search only the `post_title` of the posts