# Display post content with respect to its title?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query, array, get-the-title

I am building a custom loop where I want to display post content only if its title matches a specific string. But I am out of luck on getting this done right.

Here is my code so far.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'property',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

// The Loop
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();

    if( in_array( 'California', get_the_title() ) ){

        $post = get_page_by_title( get_the_title() );

        /*not sure how to move forward*/

    }

}

wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Any help or correct guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($post->post_title,'string_it_needs_to_match') === true){
echo the_content();

}
```

to explain

`strpos` - method of comparing strings

`===` makes sure strings are identical

Comment: Will it echo the content of the post to which we are matching the string?

Comment: it should post is set by your first line inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing the title inside the loop, you could change your query so that it searches by the title. [Other people have done stuff like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85378/13810):

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'"),   
    '%'.$title.'%' );
```

Than you'll get post object in this form:

```
foreach ( $posts as $p ) 
{
    $post = get_post( $p );
    //run your output code here
}
```